# time in strings format: python

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am using a function to bring my date consistent in a column, it goes like this

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def dateconv1(x):
   c = parse(x)
   return c
```

so if i will use it as, it works fine

```
In[15]:dateconv1("1 / 22 / 2016 15:03")
Out[15]:datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 15, 3)
```

But when I pass it in variable like this

```
a= 1 / 22 / 2016 15:03
In[16]:dateconv1(str(a))
```

It doesn't work, so how to bring it in quotes or as a string, every help will be appreciating

Comment: You're inputing the date as an expression with division rather than as a string

Comment: That's my question- how to wrap it in like this wtih some python formaule or function, because in my column it is like 1 / 22 / 2016 15:03, and str function seems not working

Comment: Why not use `parse()` the way it is instead of writing a function that calls the function only?

Comment: @evans_murithi- bec Just parse will give me datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 15, 3) something like this, but returning a variable at an end give me an exact time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that [you are talking about pandas dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825562/time-in-strings-format-python/38826094#comment65017630_38825656), you can use pandas [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

```
In [66]: dates = ['1 / 22 / 2016 15:03', 'Jul 22 2016 12:32PM', 'Jul 22 2016 5:40PM',
   ....:          'Jul 22 2016 8:31PM', 'Jul 23 2016 2:01PM', 'Jul 23 2016 7:24PM',
   ....:          'Jul 24 2016 4:30PM', 'Aug 1 2016 4:00PM', 'Aug 1 2016 7:49PM']

In [67]: df = pd.DataFrame({'d':dates})

In [68]: df.dtypes
Out[68]:
d    object
dtype: object
```

`d    object` - means that the `d` column is of a string (object) dtype

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
                     d
0  1 / 22 / 2016 15:03
1  Jul 22 2016 12:32PM
2   Jul 22 2016 5:40PM
3   Jul 22 2016 8:31PM
4   Jul 23 2016 2:01PM
5   Jul 23 2016 7:24PM
6   Jul 24 2016 4:30PM
7    Aug 1 2016 4:00PM
8    Aug 1 2016 7:49PM
```

let's convert it to `datetime` dtype:

```
In [70]: df.d = pd.to_datetime(df.d)

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
                    d
0 2016-01-22 15:03:00
1 2016-07-22 12:32:00
2 2016-07-22 17:40:00
3 2016-07-22 20:31:00
4 2016-07-23 14:01:00
5 2016-07-23 19:24:00
6 2016-07-24 16:30:00
7 2016-08-01 16:00:00
8 2016-08-01 19:49:00
```

check dtype again:

```
In [72]: df.dtypes
Out[72]:
d    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: You dont even realize, You saved my lot of time from Lamdas, try except, loops, parse, datetime and so many, Thanks

Comment: @manusharma, you are welcome. :) Please tag your question with a `pandas` tag next time when you'll ask pandas-related questions - this way you'll attract pandas specialists and will have your questions answered much faster

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a valid syntax for defining a Python variable. You should wrap with `''` or `""` to make it a string:

```
a = "1 / 22 / 2016 15:03" 
dateconv1(a)
```

Comment: Thats the question- How to wrap it in ' ' or " ", when str function is not working

Comment: @manusharma If you're reading from a file, that should already come in as a string. You can't cast expressions like so with `str`.

Comment: It is not coming as a string, thats the problem, so how to cast or wrap it under ' ' or " " is the question

Comment: Its a dateformat variable in my dataset, now its in two different formats 2016, 1, 22, 15, 3 & Jul 22 2016 12:32PM, so with the help of parsing, I am trying to bring them in same format

Comment: Please add the *dateformat variable* as it is in your dataset to your question

Comment: It looks like this Jul 22 2016 12:32PM
Jul 22 2016  5:40PM
Jul 22 2016  8:31PM
Jul 23 2016  2:01PM
Jul 23 2016  7:24PM
Jul 24 2016  4:30PM
Aug  1 2016  4:00PM
Aug  1 2016  7:49PM

Comment: Please add it to the question with proper formatting. Can't make much sense of the above.